# Export Parent Field From DevOps to a Sharepoint List using Power Automate

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I need to add a record in a Sharepoint List when a DevOps item is created using Power Automate.
All works fine using a standard approach (see the screenshots below) with the exclusion of the field "Parent".
It's not possible to select it from the Dynamic Content Popup as with other fields like ID, Work Item Type and so on.
This Parent field is present in DevOps and can be shown for example including [System.Parent] in a WIQL Query.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

My Flow

[Power Automate Flow Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVhs0.png)

Description of the labels (in Italian, sorry) in the blocks: When a new work item (which type is User Story or Test Case) is created in DevOps a new element is added in my Sharepoint list “Export DevOps With Parent”.

Here I can find almost anything, except parent:

[Power Automate Dynamic Content Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uyha.png)

Here is the WIQL showing that Parent field exists in DevOps:

[DevOps WIQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB58w.png)

Answer (score 1):

We could try below power shell script to List work item relations supported in the organization and the link type name.

```
az boards work-item relation list-type --org https://dev.azure.com/{Org name} --output table
```

Result:

[image]

and Power Automate

[image]

Comment: If have any misunderstanding, Could you re-describe more details about scenario? It's better to switch the page language back to English and capture the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I reproduced the first part (the command on Azure CLI showing that the Hierarchy-Reverse Link Type is enabled) whereas the second part is still quite unclear for me. What kind of Power Automate block did you use? In my flow the only DevOps block is the trigger at the beginning, which says "When a new Workitem is created ...." and I can't use a Link Type dropdown inside it. Thanks Again for your further help, bye.

Comment: Hi @LudovicoRistori, You are using the template Create a SharePoint list item when an Azure DevOps work item is created, right? Could you share the name of flow name in the second screenshot in the problem description here?

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT. "You are using the template Create a SharePoint list item when an Azure DevOps work item is created, right?" -> Yes, with little changes, not relevant for this question (ex: the WorkItemType condition, in grey). "Could you share the name of flow name in the second screenshot in the problem description here?" -> The step is Create Item (Sharepoint): the second screenshot contains the popup shown when you place the cursor in the "Parent" field.